ionic capacitor local notification not working if notification array have multiple notification object
dear All I am facing some issue on ionic capacitor local notification
the notification is working fine if i schedule only one notification inside notification array. but if i schedule multiple notification, it is not working
here is the code bellow
[
{
    "title": "Scheduled Notification",
    "body": "This is your 5:00 notification",
    "id": 1,
    "schedule": {
        "at": "2024-07-18T00:28:00.000Z"
    },
    "sound": null,
    "attachments": null,
    "actionTypeId": "",
    "extra": null
},
{
    "title": "Scheduled Notification",
    "body": "This is your 6:00 notification",
    "id": 2,
    "schedule": {
        "at": "2024-07-18T00:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "sound": null,
    "attachments": null,
    "actionTypeId": "",
    "extra": null
},
{
    "title": "Scheduled Notification",
    "body": "This is your 7:00 notification",
    "id": 3,
    "schedule": {
        "at": "2024-07-18T01:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "sound": null,
    "attachments": null,
    "actionTypeId": "",
    "extra": null
},
{
    "title": "Scheduled Notification",
    "body": "This is your 8:00 notification",
    "id": 4,
    "schedule": {
        "at": "2024-07-18T02:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "sound": null,
    "attachments": null,
    "actionTypeId": "",
    "extra": null
}

]
const permission = await LocalNotifications.requestPermissions();
if (permission.display === 'granted') {
  LocalNotifications.schedule({notifications}).then(data=>{
    console.log('schedule successfull: ', data);
  });
  LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationReceived', (notification) => {
    console.log('Notification recieved', notification);
  });
  LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationActionPerformed', (notification) => {
    console.log('Notification action performed', notification);
  });
} else {
  console.error('Notification permission not granted.');
}

with this, the notification is not coming. but notification is working if i set only one notification like this
 const permission = await LocalNotifications.requestPermissions();
if (permission.display === 'granted') {
  LocalNotifications.schedule({
    notifications: [
      {
        channelId: '1',
        id: 1,
        title: 'Water Reminder',
        body: 'Drink Water',
        largeIcon: 'res://drawable/drop',
        sound: 'fillwater.wav',
        extra: { type: 'w_reminder' },
        schedule: {
          at: new Date(Date.now()+15000),
          allowWhileIdle: true,
          repeats: true,
          every: 'day'
        },
      }
    ]
  });
  LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationReceived', (notification) => {
    console.log('Notification recieved', notification);
  });
  LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationActionPerformed', (notification) => {
    console.log('Notification action performed', notification);
  });
} else {
  console.error('Notification permission not granted.');
}

here is the permission section from AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

please help
